# Javascript to double size of all images in all divs of a particular class

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

So I wrote this javascript to double the images size of all images within all divs of a particular class. Here's what I came up with it.

```
var lmnts = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
for (i in lmnts) {
    if((' ' + lmnts[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + 'ClassName' + ' ') > -1) {
        var images = document.lmnts[i].getElementsByTagName('img');
        for(var j=0; j<images.length; j++)
        {
            images[j].height *= 2;
            images[j].width *= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

However I can't get it to work :(

EDIT: It's a user script. So it doesn't work means, it didn't do what it was supposed to do.
There are no errors in js console.

On debugging, i find that it enters the first loop just once and then fails after the line
`var images = document.lmnts[i].getElementsByTagName('img');`

EDIT2: It's a userscript to double the image size of all images of class `fileThumb` in 4chan.org boards.

Comment: What about it does not work? Error messages? Does nothing? Is `ClassName` really the class name you're searching for? What is an example HTML showing the problem? (Hint: http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: _"can't get it to work"_ isn't a useful problem statement.  What is happening, what isn't happening, what _exactly_ do you expect to happen, do you see any errors on the JS developer console?

Comment: Does nothing. It's a user script.
Ok finished dbging it. it fails at
`var images = document.lmnts[i].getElementsByTagName('img');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major problem would be the `var images = document.lmnts[i].getElementsByTagName('img');` line.

the `lmnts` is a variable and not a property of the `document`.

It should read  `var images = lmnts[i].getElementsByTagName('img');`

Also, instead of manually looping over all the elements in the DOM and manually testing if the `className` contains the class you want you could use the `document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName')` or the more modern `document.querySelectorAll('.ClassName')`. Using the second method you could also select all images in one go with `document.querySelectorAll('.ClassName img')`.

So all your code could be simplified to

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.ClassName img');
for (var j = 0; j < images.length; j++){
    images[j].height *= 2;
    images[j].width *= 2;
}
```

---

**Update (*based on comment*)**

The images on 4chan have a `style` attribute applied to them that sets the dimensions while the `images[j].height` sets the attribute `height` of the image. Unfortunately the `style` attribute takes precentence and show the values set from the script are not in effect.

You should alter the `style` attribute like this

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.fileThumb img');
for (var j = 0; j < images.length; j++){
    var image = images[j],
        initialWidth = parseInt(image.style.width, 10),
        initialHeight = parseInt(image.style.height, 10);

    image.style.width = (initialWidth * 2) + 'px';
    image.style.height= (initialHeight * 2) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: lol. was it that simple?
however i still can't get it to work.
Can someone confirm this on a clean html code?
I just want to rule out website specific issues.

p.s. it's a userscript to double the image size of all images of class `fileThumb` in 4chan.org boards.